# GMF Editor - Phantom Nodes

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-gmf

I'm new to GMF developement and I've got a problem. I want to program a plugin for eclipse. Therefore I use the GMF dashboard view. At first I create an ecore-file which represents the diagram shown below. Then I generate a genmodel file, with which I can create the sourcecode for some parts of the editor. Then derive a graphical definition model and a tooling definition model and combine them to a mapping model. And that's where the problems start.

In the last step when you combine the two files you can edit the Mapping. But there ist only one Node (Webpage) and one Link(categories) shown.

So if I go on an create the Diagram Editor I can only place Nodes of Webpages and Links to Categories, which are not available.

After long search I read something about "Phantom Nodes". I think, that Category and Article are such "Phantom Nodes". So I tried to prevent them by linking them with a containment to "MyWeb". But then everything is created by MyWeb. So there isn't the tree structure I'd like to have.

If I only use EMF it works fine, but not in combination with GMF.

Does someone know, how to avoid phantom nodes but keep the structure? Or is it somehow possible to work with them?

Thanks.

ps.:
I'm new, so I can't post images. Here's a link to the [diagram](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/8186/ecorediag.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put child reference inside node mapping (category) and then put another node mapping (article) inside child reference and then you will have access to other composited parts of diagram.
I have not ever heard about Phantom Nodes.